# Router navigation with lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

we have a few lazy-loading modules and router's configured like:

```
{
    path: 'parent',
    component: Parent,
    children: [
        {
            path: child1,
            loadChildren: 'pathToModule1'
        }
        {
            path: child2,
            loadChildren: 'pathToModule1'
        }
    ]
}

- child1 
{
    path: '', 
    component: Child1 
}

- child2 
{
    path: '', 
    component: Child2 
}
```

So, when i'm on the Child1 a wanna navigate to child 2 with

```
this.router.navigate(['../child2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
```

And we get **parent/child1/child2**

But in cause of empty section added with lazy loading module configuration i should use

```
this.router.navigate(['../../child2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
```

Because in fact we have **parent/child1 + ''**

**Expected behavior**

We get parent/child2
Is there any way to change this behaviour ?
Becouse with many nested lazy loading modules we'll get a littlebit
empty sections and we'll write ../../../../../../sibling to go sibling route.

**Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions**

any application with lazy loading modules. Just try navigate to sibling route.

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dBBBxpPQD1DRvN2aOWyi?p=preview)
just go down to members and try go back with two buttons

Angular version: 4.1.3

Browser: any

Comment: Hi there, Cris. Did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the current version: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17957

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to configure the Router with  `relativeLinkResolution` set to `'corrected'`.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected' })
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

See more: [`relativeLinkResolution`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#relativeLinkResolution)

> Enables a bug fix that corrects relative link resolution in components with empty paths